# In Dirac QFT, $\psi _{-} (x)|0\rangle$ isn't part of the Hilbert space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, dirac-equation

By, $\psi _{-} (x)|0\rangle$, I mean the operation:

$$\sum_{r,\vec{p}} \sqrt{\frac{m}{E_pV} }v_r(\vec{p})d^{\dagger}_r(\vec{p})e^{ipx}|0\rangle$$

The $d^{\dagger}$ creates an anti-particle

This is equal to:

$$\sum_{r,\vec{p}}\sqrt{ \frac{m}{E_pV}} v_r(\vec{p}) e^{ipx} |\vec{p}, r\rangle$$.

The $|\vec{p},r\rangle$ kets form the basis of the Fock space. And the above looks like a linear combination of such states, so it's seemingly also a part of the Fock space.

However, it's actually a linear combination with **spinor** coefficients, $v_r(\vec{p})$. Only complex number coefficients are allowed in the linear combination. So this is not really a part of the Fock space. In fact, it's actually a four-component vector.

How is it that an operator can return a vector which doesn't belong to the Fock space!?

Comment: The $v_r(p)$ are just complex numbers.  That there is an extra "spin" label on them just reflects that the $\psi$ opertor also has this label.  Different spin components of $\psi$ create different states.

Comment: @mikestone $v_r(\vec{p})$ is a four-component object even for a fixed $r$.

Comment: Yes. And each component is a different opeartor creating a different state when acting on the vacuum.

Comment: @mikestone Oh. I guess this is somewhat similar to $(P_1\vec{i}+P_2\vec{j}+P_3\vec{k})|p_1, p_2,p_3\rangle=(p_1\vec{i}+p_2\vec{j}+p_3\vec{k})|p_1,p_2,p_3\rangle$. Here too the eigenvalue is a "vector" rather than a complex number.